# R: Develop a new matrix table for each row by selecting the entire columns that have an equal value

Tags: r

I have multiple .csv files with a large matrix, ~300 rows and 2000 cols. I want to develop a new matrix table for each row by selecting the entire columns that have an equal value that is 1 . I would like to keep the row and column names and would like to create file with row names in a directory.

This the example of the datasets:

```
       pom.xml. ZooKeeper.java HBase.java Hadoop.java. BasicServer.java. Abstract.java. HBaseRegion.java
WHIRR-25        1              0          1            0                 1              1                1
WHIRR-28        1              0          1            0                 0              1                0
WHIRR-55        0              0          1            0                 0              0                0
WHIRR-61        0              0          0            0                 0              1                0
WHIRR-76        0              0          1            0                 0              0                0
WHIRR-87        1              1          1            0                 0              1                1
WHIRR-92        1              0          0            1                 0              1                1
```

So this data sets will develop an output like as below:

```
    Whirr-25
                   pom.xml. ZooKeeper.java HBase.java Hadoop.java. BasicServer.java. Abstract.java. HBaseRegion.java
 WHIRR-25        1              0          1            0                 1              1                1
 WHIRR-28        1              0          1            0                 0              1                0
 WHIRR-55        0              0          1            0                 0              0                0
 WHIRR-61        0              0          0            0                 0              1                0
 WHIRR-76        0              0          1            0                 0              0                0
 WHIRR-87        1              1          1            0                 0              1                1
 WHIRR-92        1              0          0            1                 0              1                1

Whirr-28
                pom.xml. ZooKeeper.java HBase.java Hadoop.java. BasicServer.java. Abstract.java. HBaseRegion.java
 WHIRR-28        1              0          1            0                 0              1                0
 WHIRR-55        0              0          1            0                 0              0                0
 WHIRR-61        0              0          0            0                 0              1                0
 WHIRR-76        0              0          1            0                 0              0                0
 WHIRR-87        1              1          1            0                 0              1                1
 WHIRR-92        1              0          0            1                 0              1                1

Whirr-55

             pom.xml. ZooKeeper.java HBase.java Hadoop.java. BasicServer.java. Abstract.java. HBaseRegion.java

WHIRR-55        0              0          1            0                 0              0                0
WHIRR-76        0              0          1            0                 0              0                0
WHIRR-87        1              1          1            0                 0              1                1

Whirr-61
          pom.xml. ZooKeeper.java HBase.java Hadoop.java. BasicServer.java. Abstract.java. HBaseRegion.java
WHIRR-61        0              0          0            0                 0              1                0
WHIRR-87        1              1          1            0                 0              1                1
WHIRR-92        1              0          0            1                 0              1                1

Whirr-76
               pom.xml. ZooKeeper.java HBase.java Hadoop.java. BasicServer.java. Abstract.java. HBaseRegion.java
WHIRR-76        0              0          1            0                 0              0                0
WHIRR-87        1              1          1            0                 0              1                1

Whirr-87
              pom.xml. ZooKeeper.java HBase.java Hadoop.java. BasicServer.java. Abstract.java. HBaseRegion.java
WHIRR-87        1              1          1            0                 0              1                1
WHIRR-92        1              0          0            1                 0              1                1

Whirr-92
              pom.xml. ZooKeeper.java HBase.java Hadoop.java. BasicServer.java. Abstract.java. HBaseRegion.java
 WHIRR-92        1              0          0            1                 0              1                1
```

I applied this script, but the script only create new table based on columns, not rows:

```
 dat <- read.table(file="Task_vs_Files_Proj.csv", header=T, sep=",", row.names=1) 
    dat

    apply( sapply(dat , function(x) return( as.logical(x) ) ), 2, function(x) dat[x, ])

$pom.xml.
        pom.xml. ZooKeeper.java HBase.java Hadoop.java. BasicServer.java. Abstract.java. HBaseRegion.java
    WHIRR-25        1              0          1            0                 1              1                1
    WHIRR-28        1              0          1            0                 0              1                0
    WHIRR-87        1              1          1            0                 0              1                1
    WHIRR-92        1              0          0            1                 0              1                1

    $ZooKeeper.java
             pom.xml. ZooKeeper.java HBase.java Hadoop.java. BasicServer.java. Abstract.java. HBaseRegion.java
    WHIRR-87        1              1          1            0                 0              1                1

    $HBase.java
             pom.xml. ZooKeeper.java HBase.java Hadoop.java. BasicServer.java. Abstract.java. HBaseRegion.java
    WHIRR-25        1              0          1            0                 1              1                1
    WHIRR-28        1              0          1            0                 0              1                0
    WHIRR-55        0              0          1            0                 0              0                0
    WHIRR-76        0              0          1            0                 0              0                0
    WHIRR-87        1              1          1            0                 0              1                1
```

Appreciate help from the expert here...Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating new table from a big .csv table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453483/creating-new-table-from-a-big-csv-table)

Comment: This looks like a well edited version of a question that you have marked as answered (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453483) - Why not edit that question (and not mark it accepted if the answer did not work)

Comment: @mnel yeap just want to make it more clear

Comment: I think he changed his mind about what was needed. I for one would like not to have to go back and redo an old answer to a new question.  And : If you understand what he is asking for here, _please_ answer it.

Comment: @Dwin -- whilst this new question is clearer, it just looks to be that the OP wants subsets `dat[n:nrow(dat),]` for `n in 1:nrow(dat)` - nothing to do with the columns

Comment: Please post it. I hope it's what he wants.

Comment: @mnel please. appreciate your help.

Comment: @DWin please, appreciate your help too. I know you are expert. I've been in R for 3 weeks and I need to analyze thousand lines of data in 3-4 weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you want

```
# cycle through all rows
for(which_row in seq_len(nrow(.data))){
  # get the subset of the rows from this row 
  subset_data <- .data[which_row:nrow(.data),]
  # which elements for each column == 1
  which_one <- lapply(subset_data, function(x){which(as.logical(x))})
  # drop the columns where there are no 1's
  which_one <- Filter(function(x){length(x) >0},which_one)
  # filter to those which == 1, and then get the unique combination
  # of rows (sorted to original order)
  which_rows <- sort(Reduce(union,Filter(function(x) {1 %in% x}, which_one)))
  # the file name
  file_name <- sprintf('file_%s.csv', row.names(.data)[which_row])
  # save
  write.csv(subset_data[which_rows,], file_name, row.names = T)
  # prints the data set to the console for checking
  print(subset_data[which_rows,])
  # message to show what file is created
  message(sprintf('Saving %s', file_name))
}
```

Comment: thank you. I take an example from Whirr-55. It only save with two other rows (76 and 87) because they are equalling 1 in column HBase.Java

Also,  as for Whirr-87, it is save with whirr-92 because pom.xml, Abstarct.java and HBaseRegion has are equalling to 1.

Comment: I combine the script with read.table (to read .csv datasets), but it has an error 

`Error in write.table(subset_data, file_name, header = T, include.rownames = T,  : 
  unused argument(s) (header = T, include.rownames = T)`

Comment: WHat about `Whirr-25` or any of the others? It is not at all clear what you want.

Comment: edited, a basic mistake on my part, no header argument (for reading only) -

Comment: i take whirr-28 as an example. whirr-28 is group with other rows because pom.xml is equal to 1 with whirr-87 and whirr-92. It also equalling 1 in HBase.java with whirr-55, whirr-76 and whirr-87. Also equalling 1 in Abstract.java with whirr-61, whirr-87 and whirr-92

Comment: the scripts works. i removed `include.rownames = T` because it is unused argument. But the script still not shows the output as I want

Comment: Works for me. try `file.exists('file_WHIRR-25.csv')` perhaps you are looking in the wrong place for the files

Comment: i've set the directory and the file I want to load is locataed in that directory. The console end with `+`

Comment: If you copy and run the entire code, it will work. If the console ends with a `+` then it is expecting more input. most likely you have not included the last line which is `}`. Press `esc` to clear and re-run.

Comment: it works now. I combine new proposed line with your previous code. But, seems it still not filtering appropriately. for instance, new files for whirr-61, should only have whirr-87 and whirr-92. But it appears that it still have whirr-76.

Comment: What *new proposed line?* Copy the code as it stands in the answer and it creates a file for WHIRR-61 with lines WHIRR-87 and WHIRR-92. No WHIRR-76

Comment: it works now! thank you so much for your help! really appreciate your kindness. thank you again.